# What kind of bifurcation is this?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, bifurcation

I consider the equation
$$
u_t=u_{xx}+\cos(u)-1+\Lambda,\text{ with }u\in S^1=\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}.
$$

For $0<\Lambda <2$, there are two spatially homogeneous equilibria (one is stable, the other is unstable) in $S^1$ (lousy speaking, because more precisely they are only two representative elementsts in $S^1$).

For $\Lambda=0$, the equilibria are given by $u=2\pi k, k\in\mathbb{Z}$. So on $S^1$, the only Equilibrium is $u=0$.

Linearizing the System
$$
u_x=v,\quad v_x=-\cos(u)+1-\Lambda 
$$
in $u=0$ gives the linearization matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
which has double Zero Eigenvalue.

Same for $\Lambda=2$ and linearization in $u=\pi$.

For $\Lambda <0$ and $\Lambda >2$ we have no equilibria and the Dynamics is oscillatory.

My question(s):

(1) How is this bifurcation called?I did not find the Situation where for the marginal Parameter values (here: $\lambda=0$ and $\Lambda=2$) one has *double* Zero Eigenvalue.

(2) How to see that for $\Lambda<0$ and $\Lambda>2$ we have oscillatory dynamics?